# 80s/90s zombie(?) movie with a "stolen record" of a shower scene

Tags: story-identification, movie

Many years ago there was a sci-fi movie, probably zombie kind, from 80s or 90s, that I could only see a few minutes of.

All I remember is that some guys found some dead man with a **disfigured** face or something like that in a desert, one of them I believe was also in *Robocop 3*, but I'm not sure, the other thing was, well call me stupid but, a shower scene, I remember she **turned a CCTV off**, took off her coat or jacket (beige, with maroon and green nordic patterns), opened the glass door and went to the shower, the scene ended here.

The next scene was some guy on a sofa or something, in a **control room** maybe (with monitors etc), with some scientists and we see the gal is there too (dark curly hair), she was probably a scientist also (they were all wearing lab coats); so the guy on the sofa was watching something with a **helmet-like thing, like a big white globular tablet with an antenna**, and it turns out he is secretly watching a recording of her shower! The gal smiles at him then we see the gal while in the shower (we see her from behind, just shoulders) was actually aware of that and so **she showed her middle finger** (we still see her from behind), and the guy gets like "oh wow!".

That's all I've seen, a few seconds from the beginning and those two scenes; it was a sci-fi that I really wanted to watch but had to leave for school :\ and never had the chance to know the name of the movie or anything, I really love 80s sci-fi's; and now I came across this awesome forum thought maybe somebody could help me find it?

Comment: PS: The gal was definitely alone in the shower.

Comment: Robocop 3 doesn't really have that big of a cast.  Maybe you can find him from the [IMDB cast pictures](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107978/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm) and see what else he's been in.

Comment: Thanks, already tried that :\

Answer (score 7):

I believe you may be thinking of the 1990 film, *[Hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_(film))* (bolding mine).

> **A nomad scavenger treks through an irradiated wasteland and discovers a buried robot**. He collects the pieces and takes them to junk dealer Alvy, who is talking with 'Hard Mo' Baxter, a former soldier, and Mo's friend Shades. When Alvy steps away, Mo buys the robot parts from the nomad and sells all but the head to Alvy. Intrigued by the technology, Alvy begins to research its background. Mo and Shades visit Jill, Mo's reclusive girlfriend, and, after an initially distant welcome where Jill checks them with a Geiger counter, Mo presents the robot head as a Christmas gift. Jill, a metal sculptor, eagerly accepts the head. After Shades leaves, Mo and Jill argue about a government sterilization plan and the morality of having children. **Later, they have sex, while being unknowingly watched by their foul-mouthed, perverted, voyeuristic neighbor Lincoln Weinberg via telescope**.

....

> Back at the apartment, the robot has reassembled itself using pieces of Jill's metal sculptures and recharged by draining her apartment's power network. It attempts to kill Jill, but she traps it in a room after the apartment's doors lock. **Lincoln sees the robot close the blinds while trying to peep on Jill, and, after he briefly manages to open the apartment door and sexually harasses her, offers to override the emergency lock that traps them in her apartment**. Lincoln dismisses her warnings of a killer robot, and, when he attempts to open Jill's blinds so that he can more easily peep on her, the M.A.R.K. 13 brutally kills him. Jill flees into her kitchen, where she reasons that her refrigerator will hide her from the robot's infrared vision. She damages the robot before Mo, Shades, and the apartment's security team arrive and open fire on it, apparently destroying it.

### Film Trailer

Comment: Thanks, but nope, this isn't the one, sounds interesting though, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the 1995 horror film [Mind Ripper](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114070/). The movie opens with a scene where 3 people are retrieving a body from the desert:
[image: body retrieval]. And there is a scene where a guy is watching a recording of a woman in the shower (from a CC TV camera) on what looks like a VR headset - the scene is described and partially shown in the [Good Bad Flicks review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nAH5bA6aU4) (about 50 seconds in).

The only thing that doesn't fit is the Robocop 3 connection - I can't find any cast crossovers.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer. I recently watched _Mind Ripper_ and all the plot points described in the question occur in the first ten minutes of that film.