# 1980s Sci-Fi movie with a military team hunting an alien in a desert

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was late 1980s or early 1990s when I was a kid and this movie stuck in my head.

There was a military team sent out to the desert(maybe Earth) to capture or kill an alien. During their mission there are dream-like scenes where the alien is watching the soldiers as they are in sleeping bags. Only a few people make it out alive but at the end of the movie one of characters who is a scientist is back at his lab.

He opens the door with the outline of alien in the window. A rat moves on its wheel but when he looks back up and the alien is gone.

This scene is etched in my mind and I've been wanting to know what it is.

(Note: I have been looking for an answer to this for a very long time. I have asked Google, YouTube, and recently AI for answers to this. Everywhere I look is a dead end.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see this?  (Theatre, broadcast TV, tape?)

Comment: I think it was TV, could even be a TV made movie...

Comment: Also if this helps: the alien looked human but bald, and when he stood in the window there was a bright light behind him.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c__LyGopi4U fits the bald alien, although the ending is apparently of the monster falling from the helicopter, then shown twitching.

Comment: Agree MIND RIPPER sounds like a very good fit. Desert setting too. Though, it's not actually an alien.

Comment: That's close, not sure that's a match. There were scenes in the show where the "alien" was walking over the soldiers as they slept in sleeping bags. The soldiers we're not aware of the creature at all. And the camera was made to look like a distorted dream like view of the creature.

Comment: @StevenReynolds: You can [edit] those details into your post. Was the desert on Earth?

Comment: Another option is XTRO 3: WATCH THE SKIES from 1995. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115006/?ref_=ttexr_ov_i

Comment: @cassfrank I guess that's pretty close, I was young when I saw the movie. My dad is a sci fi junkie and would watch any old movie he could get his hands on.

Comment: "was walking over the soldiers as they slept in sleeping bags" - was it inside some building or inside some tent in a desert?

Comment: It was outside in the desert

Comment: FWIW, if it were Mind Ripper, it's the unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/239220/23243

Comment: ¯⁠\⁠_⁠(⁠ツ⁠)⁠_⁠/⁠¯ honestly, this has helped accept the fact I'll never figure it out